# sum of n prime numbers java, confused

Tags: java, math, count, sum

I've read several posts on this, I even did this during one of my exams, but was in vb.net. It worked fine, however eclipse is just running non-stop when I try to execute my program, or otherwise it gives me the wrong answer. Here is my fourth attempt at it. I need to add the sum of the first n prime numbers, hence I do a check for whether a number is prime or not. The loop does not stop for some reason. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
int count = 0;
int noMod0s = 0;
int total = 0;
//static boolean prime;
for (int y = 2;count<5;y++) {
    for (int z = 1;z<y;z++) {
        if (y % z == 0) {
            noMod0s++;
        }
    }
    if (noMod0s == 1) {
        total = total + y;
        count++;
        noMod0s = 0;
    }
}
System.out.println(total);
```

Comment: I recommend writing out a correct algorithm using pseudo code.  Then, attempt something in Java.

Comment: Niver answered, I just needed to reset one of my counters. Thanks though. I've done this code in vb.net, but yes pseudocode would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two issues with your code:

- You are not resetting variable `noMod0s` for each separate primality test. You should do it before the second loop.
- The second loop should start from 2 not 1 to be a valid primality test. Of course in this case you will be comparing `noMod0s == 0`. It works the same but it gives a clearer idea of what the code is doing.

Comment: thank you so much!!! I literally just added noMod0s = 0; at the top of my first for loop and it has fixed everything!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :)

Comment: The reason why it is 1 instead of 2 is because I need to test 2 to be a prime number and then my second loop has a validation that z < y, therefore if it only has 1 in the noMod0s, then it is prime. So if I made it 2, then z would not be less than y and it would not run the second loop.

Comment: @SalmanChishti I understand but as I wrote you will be comparing against 0 if you start from `z=2`. Anyway this is opinion based, the first point was the issue.

Comment: accepted it as answer now! I had to wait 5 minutes for some reason. Thanks again, yeah I understand, depends how you look at it.

Comment: "You should do it before the second loop." Even better, declare it inside the loop. It doesn't need to be in a broader scope; and by putting it in this right scope, there would have been no possibility *not* to set it to zero before using it.

Comment: @AndyTurner True. There are also other optimizations that can be done also but I limited the answer on the bare minimum to change in order to fix the code.